# move items from one listbox to another listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox, silverlight-4.0

I need to move items from one listbox to another listbox on button click event in silverlight Application.

I use the follow code,

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem);

            if (ListBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox2.SelectedValue);
                ListBox2.Items.Remove(ListBox2.SelectedValue);
            }

        }
```

But If I try to use that above code it give the following Error,

```
operation not supported on read-only collection
```

How can solve this problem ??

Comment: @Michay No .. I diddnt use

Comment: @Michay OP probably didn't do that, because there is no DataSource property in WPF or Silverlight. The question is not about WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

You should use data binding to bind `ObservableCollection`s of items to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` properties of your two `ListBox`es:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Your1stCollectionProperty}" ... />

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Your2ndCollectionProperty}" ... />
```

Then to move items, you just adjust the actual collections rather than try to adjust the `ListBoxItem`s:

```
var itemToMove = Your1stCollectionProperty.ElementAt(indexOfItemToRemove);
Your1stCollectionProperty.Remove(itemToMove);
Your2ndCollectionProperty.Add(itemToMove);
```